# Finding a solution to the following conditions?

Tags: recurrence-relation

So for these 5 conditions, I am trying to find the solution/formula for them. 
What would $a_n$ equal basically? If it helps, the recurrence relation these 5 conditions were generated from was $a_n = a_{n - 1} + 2n$.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

$$
\begin{align*}
a_0 &= 4 \\
a_1 &=  6 \\
a_2 &= 10 \\
a_3 &= 16 \\
a_4 &= 24
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are infinitely many sequences starting $4,6,10,16,24$. If I understand you correctly, this sequence was generating according to the rule $a_n = a_{n-1} + 2n$ with the initial value $a_0 = 4$. In that case, you have
$$
a_n = a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n (2k) = a_0 + 2 \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = n^2 + n + 4.
$$

Comment: Yes that is it, also thank you for editing my initial post, I am pretty new at this and am pretty bad at formatting correctly.